# Extracting MachineBasicBlock from Branch Instruction

Tags: llvm, machine-instruction

The branch instruction contains labels which are the names of the basicblocks that it might jump to. Given that, is there a way to extract a MachineBasicBlock object from a branching instruction? for example:

```
for(MachineBasicBlock &BB : MF){
    for(MachineInstr &MI : BB){
      if(MI.isConditionalBranch()){
        MachineBasicBlock &InstBB = something(MI.getOperand(0));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you cast `MI`'s operand to [BasicBlockSDNode](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlockSDNode.html) and then use `getBasicBlock()`. Remember to perform the casting using LLVM `cast<>()` function.